# Update Multi Rows SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

i have two tables

```
->DESC TABLE1
SC_CD                                    VARCHAR2(2)
DOC_AMT                                  NUMBER(10,2)
DEPOSIT_BANK                             VARCHAR2(2)

-> DESC TABLE2
SC_CD                                    VARCHAR2(2)
DOC_AMT                                  NUMBER(10,2)
DEPOSIT_BANK                             VARCHAR2(2)

->SELECT * FROM TABLE1;
SC   DOC_AMT DE
-- --------- --
       78350 70
       15840 70
        3750 70

->SELECT * FROM TABLE2;
SC   DOC_AMT DE
-- --------- --
1       78350 70
6         840 80
3        3750 70
```

NOW, i want to update TABLE1 SC_CD from TABLE2 SC_CD

After update, i want this result...

```
->SELECT * FROM TABLE1;
SC   DOC_AMT DE
-- --------- --
 1     78350 70
       15840 70
 3      3750 70
```

Thanks

Comment: Oracle or mysql? and what have you tried so far?

Comment: i tried Oracle 10g

Comment: How do you match rows in the two tables, by `doc_amt` alone or by `doc_amt` and `deposit_bank`?

Comment: SO is not a place where people write code for you, but a place where you should ask specific questions, posting your attempts.

Comment: @mathguy Yes.. i match with DOC_AMT and DEPOSIT_BANK

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

SQL Server

```
update TABLE1 
set SC_CD = a.SC_CD 
from TABLE2 a 
where DOC_AMT = a.DOC_AMT and DEPOSIT_BANK = a.DEPOSIT_BANK
```

ORACLE

```
update TABLE1 
set SC_CD = (SELECT SC_CD 
             FROM TABLE2 
             WHERE TABLE1.DOC_AMT = TABLE2.DOC_AMT 
               AND TABLE1 .DEPOSIT_BANK = TABLE2.DEPOSIT_BANK)
```

Answer is update

Comment: Why would you think that? Originally the post was tagged with MySQL and Oracle (now corrected to show only Oracle) - where did you see MS SQL?

Answer (score 0):

Best solution for this kind of problem is the `MERGE` statement, like so:

```
merge into table1 t1
  using table2 t2
  on (     t1.doc_amt      = t2.doc_amt 
       and t1.deposit_bank = t2.deposit_bank)
when matched then update 
                    set t1.sc_cd = t2.sc_cd;
```

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9016.htm